# How can I extract the item id from the response in Scrapy?

Tags: scrapy

```
    import scrapy


    class FarmtoolsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'farmtools'
    allowed_domains = ['www.donedeal.ie']
    start_urls = ['https://www.donedeal.ie/farmtools/']

    def parse(self, response):
        rows = response.xpath('//ul[@class="card-collection"]/li')

        for row in rows:
            yield {
                'item_id': row.xpath('.//a/@href').get(),
                'item_title': row.xpath('.//div[1]/p[@class="card__body- 
                  title"]/text()').get(),
                'item_county': row.xpath('.//ul[@class="card__body- 
                  keyinfo"]/li[2]/text()').get(),
                'item_price': 
                  row.xpath('.//p[@class="card__price"]/span[1]/text()').get()
                  }
```

I want to extract the item number from the item_id response which is a url.
Is it possible to do this?
The response looks like this:

```
    {'item_id': 'https://www.donedeal.ie/farmtools-for-sale/international-784- 
    tractor/25283884?campaign=3', 'item_title': 'INTERNATIONAL 784 TRACTOR', 
    'item_county': 'Derry', 'item_price': '3,000'}
```

I'd appreciate any advice, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somethink like this would work. Not clean but still, spliting the string up until you get the id you want.

```
def parse(self, response):
    rows = response.xpath('//ul[@class="card-collection"]/li')
    

    for row in rows:
        link = row.xpath('.//a/@href').get()
        link_split = link.split('/')[-1]
        link_id = link_split.split('?')[0]
        yield {
            'item_id': link_id,
            'item_title': row.xpath('.//div[1]/p[@class="card__body 
                           title"]/text()').get(),
            'item_county': row.xpath('.//ul[@class="card__body- 
                           keyinfo"]/li[2]/text()').get(),
            'item_price': 
              row.xpath('.//p[@class="card__price"]/span[1]/text()').get()
            }
```

Update in response to comment

### Complete code example

```
import scrapy


class TestSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'test'
    allowed_domains = ['donedeal.ie']
    start_urls = ['https://www.donedeal.ie/farmtools/']

    def parse(self, response):
        rows = response.xpath('//ul[@class="card-collection"]/li')
        for row in rows:
            link = row.xpath('.//a/@href').get()
            link_split = link.split('/')[-1]
            link_id = link_split.split('?')[0]
            yield { 
                'item_id':link_id,
                'item_title': row.xpath('.//p[@class="card__body-title"]/text()').get(),
                'item_county': row.xpath('.//ul[@class="card__body-keyinfo"]/li[2]/text()').get(),
                'item_price': row.xpath('.//p[@class="card__price"]/span[1]/text()').get()
        }
```

A note, when looping over each 'card', you don't need to specify the div if you're aiming to get a selector with a unique class like card__body-title.

Please note that yielding a dictionary is one of three ways thinking about grabbing data from Scrapy. Consider using items and itemloaders.

Items: [Here](https://youtu.be/E6lOVwigsNA)

ItemLoaders: [Here](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/loaders.html)

ItemLoaders Example: [Here](https://github.com/IgoMedeiros/scrapy-with-itemloader/tree/master/verduca)

Comment: Hi Aaron, thanks for your help. It returned the item_id of the first item but that was all. The other items - title, county and price returned "None" and it only returned the first line.

Comment: Thanks again Aaron

Answer (score 0):

A cleaner alternative would be to use [regex](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html). You can even use it with Scrapy selectors ([docs](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html#using-selectors-with-regular-expressions))

```
'item_title': row.xpath('.//div[1]/p[@class="card__body-title"]/text()').re_first(r'/(\d+)\?campaign')
```

In the snippet above, the regex will return a string with only the digits between `/` and `?campaign`.

In this particular URL `https://www.donedeal.ie/farmtools-for-sale/international-784-tractor/25283884?campaign=3` it would return `'25283884'`

**Edited:** Corrected the regex

Comment: Thanks for your help renatodvc .

Comment: Nice! I've never really liked regex but for something simple like this, I may have to revisit it.